# Webpack build failing on upgrading Nextjs to v10 from v9

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js, antd, webpack-4

I'm quite new to frontend technologies. I tried Next.js `v9.x.x` and anyhow configured `next.config.js` to support `less` as well as `.css` files as [AntDesign](https://ant.design/) needed it which I'm using in the project. Here is the`next.config.js` file which perfectly worked with Next.js-v9.x.x:

```
const themeVariables = lessToJS(
  fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, './assets/theme.less'), 'utf8'),
);

const plugins = [
  [withLess({
    lessLoaderOptions: {
      javascriptEnabled: true,
      modifyVars: themeVariables, // make your antd custom effective
    },
    webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
      if (isServer) {
        const antStyles = /antd\/.*?\/style.*?/;
        const origExternals = [...config.externals];
        config.externals = [
          (context, request, callback) => {
            if (request.match(antStyles)) return callback();
            if (typeof origExternals[0] === 'function') {
              origExternals[0](context, request, callback);
            } else {
              callback();
            }
          },
          ...(typeof origExternals[0] === 'function' ? [] : origExternals),
        ];

        config.module.rules.unshift({
          test: antStyles,
          use: 'null-loader',
        });
      }

      const builtInLoader = config.module.rules.find((rule) => {
        if (rule.oneOf) {
          return (
            rule.oneOf.find((deepRule) => deepRule.test && deepRule.test.toString().includes('/a^/')) !== undefined
          );
        }
        return false;
      });

      if (typeof builtInLoader !== 'undefined') {
        config.module.rules.push({
          oneOf: [
            ...builtInLoader.oneOf.filter((rule) => (rule.test && rule.test.toString().includes('/a^/')) !== true),
          ],
        });
      }

      config.resolve.alias['@'] = path.resolve(__dirname);

      // SVGs loading
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.svg$/,
        issuer: {
          test: /\.(js|ts)x?$/,
        },
        use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
      });

      return config;
    },
  })],
];

module.exports = withPlugins(plugins, nextConfig);
```

I just found that a major version (`10.x.x`) released by Next.js. I upgraded the project and the build started failing with:

```
Failed to compile.
Error: No module factory available for dependency type: CssDependency

> Build error occurred
Error: > Build failed because of webpack errors
  at build (/Users/ss/Projects/Test/Frontend/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:15:918)
  at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
  at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

Tried finding solutions online and found [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/5030) that a missing `mini-css-extract-plugin` configuration might raise this error. I was confused as the same was working earlier so thought that they removed this dependency in the latest release but couldn't find any issue raised for this in their [Github repo](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues).

On debugging the project, I also found that `mini-css-extract-plugin` was missing in `package-lock.json > "next" > "requires"` section in v10.x.x while it was there in v9.x.x

Now I'm confused about how to re-configure the `next.config.js` for my case as I couldn't find any solutions online.

Can anyone please check? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure if it'll help, but I also ran into an issue with webpack and nextjs. Try adding `future: { webpack5: true }` to the module.exports in next.config.js.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I fixed it by splitting the plugin to look like this:

```
module.exports = withPlugins([[
  withLess, {
    lessLoaderOptions: {
      javascriptEnabled: true,
      modifyVars: themeVariables, // make your antd custom effective
    },
    webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
      if (isServer) {
        const antStyles = /antd\/.*?\/style.*?/;
        const origExternals = [...config.externals];
        config.externals = [
          (context, request, callback) => {
            if (request.match(antStyles)) return callback();
            if (typeof origExternals[0] === 'function') {
              origExternals[0](context, request, callback);
            } else {
              callback();
            }
          },
          ...(typeof origExternals[0] === 'function' ? [] : origExternals),
        ];

        config.module.rules.unshift({
          test: antStyles,
          use: 'null-loader',
        });
      }

      const builtInLoader = config.module.rules.find((rule) => {
        if (rule.oneOf) {
          return (
            rule.oneOf.find((deepRule) => deepRule.test && deepRule.test.toString().includes('/a^/')) !== undefined
          );
        }
        return false;
      });

      if (typeof builtInLoader !== 'undefined') {
        config.module.rules.push({
          oneOf: [
            ...builtInLoader.oneOf.filter((rule) => (rule.test && rule.test.toString().includes('/a^/')) !== true),
          ],
        });
      }

      config.resolve.alias['@'] = path.resolve(__dirname);

      // SVGs loading
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.svg$/,
        issuer: {
          test: /\.(js|ts)x?$/,
        },
        use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
      });

      return config;
    },
  }]], nextConfig);
```

If this doesn't help, you can use this package [next-plugin-antd-less](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-plugin-antd-less)

Using it with `next-compose-plugins` you'll have to follow the same structure as the above.

```
module.exports = withPlugins([
  [
    withAntdLess,
    {
      lessVarsFilePath: "./assets/theme.less",
    },
  ],
])
```